# Gostaria de sugestões a cerca dessa estrutura em JS

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde. Praticando um pouco, resolvi construir um slider em javascript, e optei em seguir essa linha de construção com um construtor. O código está funcional.
Porém, gostaria de encapsular o máximo possível toda a estrutura de código. Mas não consegui encaixar o trecho a seguir dentro do corpo do objeto:

```
novoSlider.btnProx.onclick = function () {
    novoSlider.prox();
}
novoSlider.btnPrev.onclick = function () {
    novoSlider.prev();
}
```

Código completo:

```
<script>
    var sliderJs = function () {
        var elements = [];
        var pos = 0;
        var btnProx;
        var btnPrev;

        this.construtor = function (proxId, prevId, objJson) {
            this.btnProx = document.getElementById(proxId);
            this.btnPrev = document.getElementById(prevId);
            elements = objJson;
            container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
            container.style.transition = "all .3s";
            container.style.backgroundImage = "url("+elements[pos].url+")";
        };

        this.prox = function () {
            if(pos != elements.length-1){
                pos = pos + 1;
                container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
                container.style.backgroundImage = "url("+elements[pos].url+")";
            }else{
                pos = 0;
                container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
                container.style.backgroundImage = "url("+elements[pos].url+")";
            }   
        };
        this.prev = function () {
            if(pos != 0){
                pos = pos -1;
                container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
                container.style.backgroundImage = "url("+elements[pos].url+")";
            }else{
                pos = elements.length-1;
                container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
                container.style.backgroundImage = "url("+elements[pos].url+")";
            }
        };
    };


    window.onload = function () {

        var objElements = [
            {titulo : "Jogador é demitido",
            url : "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Vp4z1HqcVWQ/VfcI2mUUjSI/AAAAAAAABMQ/t10j6_O6lEE/s300-c/infidelidade2.jpg" },
            {titulo : "Cunha abre processo de impeatchment",
            url : "http://www.atoananet.com.br/links/2015/08/11/artista-tranforma-fotos-aleatorias-em-divertidas-ilustracoes_300.jpg" },
            {titulo : "MegaSena acumulada", 
            url : "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8rt58bwMhTs/U_1SXIg8FSI/AAAAAAAAEMY/A3DZRYdMGSY/s300-c/cat01.jpg" }
        ];

        var novoSlider = new sliderJs();
        novoSlider.construtor("prox","ant",objElements);

        novoSlider.btnProx.onclick = function () {
            novoSlider.prox();
        }
        novoSlider.btnPrev.onclick = function () {
            novoSlider.prev();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A variável `container` é global? ela vem de onde?

Comment: Em relação à tua pergunta podias fazer `this.btnPrev.addEventListener('click', this.prev);` e o mesmo para o `prox`

Comment: Funcionou. Cheguei a testar isso, mas ao invés de click, coloquei onclick. 
Obrigado. E container, é um elemento que vai conter o slider. ele não está diretamente definido no código pq a referência está sendo feita direto ao id do elementoc(como se fosse uma variável, e é) sem o getElementById. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vejo no teu código podes melhorar algumas coisas.

Não precisas dessa lógica de construtor. Podes usar diretamente esses argumentos quando chamas o `new sliderJs`.

Juntei o `container` como argumento e retirei algum código duplicado...

```
 var sliderJs = function(proxId, prevId, elements, container) {
     var pos = 0;
     this.container = container;
     this.btnProx = document.getElementById(proxId);
     this.btnPrev = document.getElementById(prevId);
     this.container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
     this.container.style.transition = "all .3s";
     this.container.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + elements[pos].url + ")";

     this.prox = function() {
         pos = pos != elements.length - 1 ? pos + 1 : 0;
         this.container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
         this.container.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + elements[pos].url + ")";

     };
     this.prev = function() {
         pos = pos != 0 ? pos - 1 : elements.length - 1;
         this.container.childNodes[1].textContent = elements[pos].titulo;
         this.container.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + elements[pos].url + ")";
     };
     this.btnProx.addEventListener('click', this.prox);
     this.btnPrev.addEventListener('click', this.prev);
 };


 window.onload = function() {

     var objElements = [{
         titulo: "Jogador é demitido",
         url: "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Vp4z1HqcVWQ/VfcI2mUUjSI/AAAAAAAABMQ/t10j6_O6lEE/s300-c/infidelidade2.jpg"
     }, {
         titulo: "Cunha abre processo de impeatchment",
         url: "http://www.atoananet.com.br/links/2015/08/11/artista-tranforma-fotos-aleatorias-em-divertidas-ilustracoes_300.jpg"
     }, {
         titulo: "MegaSena acumulada",
         url: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8rt58bwMhTs/U_1SXIg8FSI/AAAAAAAAEMY/A3DZRYdMGSY/s300-c/cat01.jpg"
     }];

     var novoSlider = new sliderJs("prox", "ant", objElements, document.getElementById('container'));
 }
```

Comment: Parece que este código não está funcional. 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined"
A variável container está apontando pro null.

Comment: @ErickLemos na minha resposta usei a lógica `this.container`. Se queres continuar a usar com tinhas o `container` deves mudar no código `this.container` para somente `container`. Se ainda não funcionar faz um jsFiddle que eu ajudo a corrigir.